# How to display which file differs from the others

Tags: diff

I'm trying to write a script to get info from 5 different places and compare them for differences.  The information is simply IP addresses and I have them placed in text files.  I'm using:

```
diff --from-file file1 file2 file3 file4 file5
```

to compare them and it works, but I need to display which file contains different information.  I expect only one or at most two files not to match.

Comment: I really which there was a decent answer to this. I like `-u` for some things, but for a 6 file diff, it is unmanageable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change the diff format to unified with `-u` or `--unified`, the filenames will appear.

```
# diff -u --from-file file1 file[2-5]
--- file1   2020-10-30 11:02:22.223269990 +0200
+++ file3   2020-10-30 11:02:35.445984702 +0200
@@ -1 +1 @@
-original
+new
--- file1   2020-10-30 11:02:22.223269990 +0200
+++ file5   2020-10-30 11:02:40.625872942 +0200
@@ -1 +1 @@
-original
+new
```

You can also use a brief output with `-q` or `--brief`.

```
# diff -q --from-file file1 file[2-5]
Files file1 and file3 differ
Files file1 and file5 differ
```

Another solution might be to run a checksum program, e.g. md5sum, sha1sum, etc. on all the files and see which one has a different checksum than the first one.

On a GNU system you can even combine it with **awk** like this:

```
# md5sum file* | awk '{h[$1] = h[$1] " " $2} END {for(k in h) printf("%s:%s\n", k, h[k])}'
88fa9f694690e11239096536ccf2702b: file1 file2 file4
9cd599a3523898e6a12e13ec787da50a: file3 file5
```

Or you can combine it with [**uniq**](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/uniq-invocation.html) like this:

```
# hashlen=32  # MD5 outputs 32 hexadecimals
# md5sum file* | sort | uniq --group --check-chars=${hashlen}
88fa9f694690e11239096536ccf2702b  file1
88fa9f694690e11239096536ccf2702b  file2
88fa9f694690e11239096536ccf2702b  file4

9cd599a3523898e6a12e13ec787da50a  file3
9cd599a3523898e6a12e13ec787da50a  file5
```

On a FreeBSD system you can combine it with **awk** like this:

```
# md5 file* | awk -F ' = ' '{h[$2] = h[$2] " " substr($1, index($1, "("))} END {for(k in h) printf("%s:%s\n", k, h[k])}' 
9cd599a3523898e6a12e13ec787da50a: (file3) (file5)
88fa9f694690e11239096536ccf2702b: (file1) (file2) (file4)
```

Answer (score 2):

[diffuse](http://diffuse.sourceforge.net/) can handle the 5 inputs (sudo apt-get install diffuse). From the man page:

```
Diffuse is a graphical tool for merging and comparing text files. Diffuse is able
to compare an arbitrary number of files side-by-side and gives users the ability
to manually adjust line matching and directly edit files.
```

Answer (score 1):

If only one file is different, then you can use like

```
md5sum file* | uniq -f 2
```

`uniq -f 2` will avoid field 2 (file name).

Comment: [GNU md5sum](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/md5sum-invocation.html) outputs two fields - the hash and the filename - so `-f 2` will skip both and **uniq** will practically do nothing except printing the hash of the first file. The contents of the files will be irrelevant.